# Using different logic for the same respond_to format in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, respond-to

My Rails application is currently using JSON as the `respond_to` format for AJAX forms on the site. I'm planning to create a public API for the application, and I'd like to use JSON for it also. How might I distinguish between an AJAX form and an API call in my controllers if the requested format for both is JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you keep the public api in a separate controller, and have a different route since you say you have different logic. You can have namespaced controllers such as `app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb` and namespace your routes like:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

and leave your existing controllers with ajax actions used by your site as they are.